# Finding for unicode word in Post Response

Tags: python, post, http-post, python-requests

I use POST method to login automatically on my account and I want do stuff.

Now I want to check if The string `خطا` is NOT in login page print `ok`.

But it doesn't work. why?

```
post_data = {'email':email, 'password':password}
post_response = requests.post(url='http://test.come/login', data=post_data)
if post_response.text.find(u'\xd8\xae\xd8\xb7\xd8\xa7') == -1:
    print 'OK'
```

Comment: I Updated it thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to put UTF-8 bytes in a unicode string. Either decode from UTF-8 or test for the actual text:

```
>>> '\xd8\xae\xd8\xb7\xd8\xa7'.decode('utf8')
u'\u062e\u0637\u0627'
>>> print '\xd8\xae\xd8\xb7\xd8\xa7'.decode('utf8')
خطا
```

so use:

```
if u'\u062e\u0637\u0627' not in post_response.text:
```

or if you have [declared a suitable source encoding](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/):

```
if u'خطا' not in post_response.text:
```

or

```
if '\xd8\xae\xd8\xb7\xd8\xa7'.decode('utf8') not in post_response.text:
```

or, if the original response is encoded in UTF-8 as well, even:

```
if '\xd8\xae\xd8\xb7\xd8\xa7' not in post_response.content:
```

You may want to read up about Python and Unicode. I recommend:

- Ned Batchelder's [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- Joel Spolsky's [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: can I use `not in` rather than `in` ? if خطا is not in response print OK?

Comment: @MortezaLSC: ah, you use *equals to* `-1`. Sure you can.

Comment: @MortezaLSC: and what has `jiāāā` got to do with the Persian word for *Error*?